# Working with objects in array from REST response

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to get an array of objects from an API.

I get an array that looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "position": "TestEmployee",
    "salary": 20000,
    "managerid": 1
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "position": "TestEmployee",
    "salary": 20000,
    "managerid": 1
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "John Crack",
    "position": "TestEmployee",
    "salary": 20000,
    "managerid": 1
}]
```

And from these objects I need to find one by the name and get its Id. In C# this would be possible by creating a list of objects and get it with LINQ.

How can I get this with Python?

Comment: Python has the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) standard library module for parsing JSON objects and arrays to Python dictionaries and lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn you list of dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
responses = [{
"id": 5,
"name": "John Doe",
"position": "TestEmployee",
"salary": 20000,
"managerid": 1
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "John Smith",
"position": "TestEmployee",
"salary": 20000,
"managerid": 1
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "John Crack",
"position": "TestEmployee",
"salary": 20000,
"managerid": 1
}]
```

Then define the function:

```
def response2dict(responses):
    responsedict = {}
    for response in responses:
        responsedict[response["name"]] = {}
        for key,value in response.items():
            responsedict[response["name"]][key]=value
    return responsedict
    

responsedict = response2dict(responses)
```

Then you can easily access the record as:

```
responsedict["John Doe"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your question, how to get the list element by id in python?

Then you should be good to go with this:

```py
api_response = [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "position": "TestEmployee",
        "salary": 20000,
        "managerid": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "John Smith",
        "position": "TestEmployee",
        "salary": 20000,
        "managerid": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "John Crack",
        "position": "TestEmployee",
        "salary": 20000,
        "managerid": 1,
    },
]

def find_by_id(search_id):
    for e in api_response:
        if e["id"] is search_id:
            return e
    return None

print ( find_by_id(5) )
```

If your question ism how to parse JSON objects, check out pythons standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html .